# Java - Finding native Bits Per Point

Tags: java, graphics, dpi, toolkit, bpp

I need to find the Bits Per Point, height, width, and refresh rate of the local machine.

I know how to find most of this using java.awt.Toolkit, but the Toolkit.getScreenResolution returns a value in Dots-Per-Inch.

I can't just retool the (fairly massive) entire program to use DPI instead of BPP, and don't entirely know the difference anyway.

Is there a way in java to grab the BPP of the local display?

Comment: BPP and DPI are completely unrelated. Why do you need to know the screen's BPP?

Answer (score 0):

I later found that this can be done using java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment, GraphicsDevice, and DisplayMode

DisplayMode gives the data needed.